# How do I count how many ways to place 8 cards of only 2 ranks (suits ignored) into 16 possible positions?

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

I have a need to generate all combinations of placing 8 standard playing cards of only 2 distinct ranks, (suits are ignored), into 16 possible positions.  For example, suppose we had A A A A 2 2 2 2 and had 16 positions to put them into so that the first one might look like this:

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ A A A A 2 2 2 2 and the next one might look like this _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ A A A 2 A 2 2 2. The very last combination might be 2 2 2 2 A A A A _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _.

How do I count these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose four spaces of the sixteen for the first rank (how many ways?) then choose four spaces (out of how many) for the second rank (how many ways?)

Comment: But that doesn't take into consideration the repeating ranks does it?  For example, if the 8 cards were A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 the answer would be different than if the cards were A,A,A,A,2,2,2,2 like here.

Comment: Yes it does.  That is why you choose all four spaces together.  You choose four but don't care which Ace goes in which space you have chosen.

Comment: so would it be (16 choose 4) * (12 choose 4) = 900,900?

Comment: I didn't check the arithmetic, but the left side is correct.